# Can I add OptimisticResponse for different __typename than Mutation response returns?

Tags: graphql, apollo, mutation

I use Apollo Client v3 and I have some data of type `__typename: 'Entity'` and this data has nested array under key `relation` of items of type `__typename: 'Relation'` and I also have mutation that updates that relations and it returns data back in response of type `__typename: 'Relation'`. It does not update on UI when data comes back after the mutation - I assume that my relations data I displayed on the UI is actually nested within another `__typename` and what I would like to achieve is when I run my mutation for update my relation data then my displayed list on UI will also be updated - let's say by `Optimistic Response` or something similar.

Is it achievable with that combination of Query and Mutation ?

Cheers!